# Increase font size when viewport width decreases

Tags: css, viewport, font-size, clamp

I would like to know if there is a CSS command allowing to increase the font size when the viewport width becomes smaller (like a reverse clamp method).
In fact, I want to do the opposite of what clamp does (as the first entry is the MIN value).
I searched on internet without success.
Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: have a look at css `calc`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `calc` to subtract from a font-size based on the width of the viewport which will give you the inverted scaling you desire.

You can then still use clamp as desired with a min/max value.

Run the snippet below as full page.

```css
h1 {
 font-size: clamp(10px, calc(100px - 5vw), 100px); 
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your helpful feedback !! I just tried and it works fine for me ;)